WPF: In custom scroll viewer, vertical scroll bar is thicker than horizontal scroll bar
I am using WPF for an application. In the XAML code, I have defined the width & height of both horizontal scroll bar and vertical scroll bar. However, the vertical scroll bar is still thicker than horizontal one.
<Window x:Class="Sanganak._05_0_00_Main"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sanganak"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Sanganak" Height="900" Width="900" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Background="#162D2D" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown" >
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="ScrollThumbs" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Fill="Transparent" />
                                <Border x:Name="Rectangle1" CornerRadius="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Horizontal">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="Height" Value="7"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Vertical">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="Width" Value="7"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <!--Scroll Bars-->
            <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}" >
                <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#404C54" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="10" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}" >
                            <Grid x:Name="GridRoot" Width="12" Background="{x:Null}">
                                <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="0" IsDirectionReversed="True" Focusable="False">
                                    <Track.Thumb>
                                        <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{DynamicResource ScrollThumbs}"/>
                                    </Track.Thumb>
                                    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                        <RepeatButton x:Name="PageUp" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="False"/>
                                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                        <RepeatButton x:Name="PageDown" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="False"/>
                                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                </Track>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger SourceName="Thumb" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Value="{DynamicResource ButtonSelectBrush}" TargetName="Thumb" Property="Background"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger SourceName="Thumb" Property="IsDragging" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Value="{DynamicResource DarkBrush}" TargetName="Thumb" Property="Background"/>                                            
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Thumb" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                                    <Setter TargetName="GridRoot" Property="LayoutTransform" >
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter TargetName="PART_Track" Property="LayoutTransform" >
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="12"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Thumb" Property="Tag" Value="Horizontal"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="PageDown" Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="PageUp" Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand"/>
                                </Trigger>                                
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>            
        </ResourceDictionary>        
    </Window.Resources>    
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Background="Transparent" >
            <Frame x:Name="Frame01" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>

I have written the code and tried multiple ways to fix. However, I have been unsuccessful.

At least x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" is wrong.

When the Tag of Thumb can become "Vertical"?

I am not sure I understood your comment. Is "Vertical" not the appropriate property for Tag of Thumb?
also, can you suggest what needs to be changed to achieve my desired outcome?

Unless you set "Vertical" to Tag, <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Vertical"> will never be  invoked.

Got it. I added the  and now it works.

I added the <Setter TargetName="Thumb" Property="Tag" Value="Vertical"/> and now it works just fine.

Can you please elaborate what you have added and what exactly has solved your problem?

@ˈvɔlə A simple, 2-character edit fixed the problem with the 'missing code' in this answer.
